# What would be causing SQL server to give does not exist or acces denied

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL server 2005 DB that is accessed by an MSACCESS database using link tables.

Occasionally we are getting SQL server does not esit or access denied messages
when a works fine at most other times. From clients this is of course.

What we be some possible causes of this??

Malcolm

EDIT: This is actually a ODBC message.

Answer (score 0):

We've seen *intermittent* errors caused by distance and firewalls, epsecially for non-default instances. By distance I mean clients in new York and we're in Switzerland. Fewer issues in London, zero in Switzerland.

We moved to "server.domain.tld\instancename,port" and all issues disappeared.
This avoids an extra roundtrip (to port 1434) to find the instance port

Comment: @gbn:That's interesting, so in your case the additional latency was being caused by the local network?

Comment: I'm based in Switzerland and distant clients had the issue. Simply, it was too many firewalls and latency messing up Kerberos, in conjunction with the overhead of resolving the instance port

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the server does exist and access is granted this is usually down to network problems or the server load is too high for it to respond.

Comment: Wouldn't you expect a timeout message instead of this??